# How to constraint with objects out of sketch plane?

Tags: solidworks

I would like to constraint the centers of two rectangles to be exactly across the part central axis (shown in the middle of cylindrical hole)

[image]

Is it possible?

---

Rectangles should be as wide as circular hole

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many, many different ways to constrain this sketch. You haven't given any details on your actual design intent, however.

Looking at your screenshots, and your comment to NMech, I have assumed that you wish the rectangles to be as wide as the circle itself. In your headline question, you dimensioned this manually (rather than with an equation linking to the circle diameter, which would have been better), and ask how to centre it on the axis. In this case, you could put a construction line, use a colinear constraint to match this to the axis, and then set the two sides of your rectangle to be symmetric about the construction line using a symmetry constraint.

Have a look at the .gif below, though - it's another way to get the same shape. The point of me showing this is to say, that your question doesn't give enough information in order to determine the best recommendation.

What are the key dimensions? what might change? What does the part *do*? how is it manufactured?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update: To get the outer side of the cylinder, (expanding on Johathan R Swift's aswer) I would:

- create a plane where you want the rectangle to be.
- Start a sketch on that plane
- Use **Convert entities** to the inner edges of the circular bit.
- use those *Converted Entities* as guides to create a center construction line, between the edges.
- use the construction line to center the rectangles
- Dimension the rectangle width on an Equation (with the diameter of the cylinder).

Comment: I need rectangles be as wide as outer edges :)